# Cakephp model with several datasources

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model called `Forwards` this model uses a table from my Database. However it is required for some of the views connected to this model to use my costum datasource (This is a datasource i have created which links it to an API).

Now my question how can i add a `datasource` to a Model that already has a `datasource`.

And how can i tell the `Paginator` that it has to use this datasource when it is paginating (so it doesnt confilct)

**Update**

I have been reading abit it seems the only way to use two datasource in a model is to Hack abit, so i was wondering is it possible to use two models from one controller while still paginating?

**i want to keep these settings**

```
public $paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Offer.id',
        'Offer.name',
        'OfferUrl.preview_url',
        'Stat.ltr',
        'Stat.cpc',
        'Category.name',
        'Country.name')

, 'conditions' => array('Stat.date' => array(
            'conditional' => 'BETWEEN'
        , 'values' => array()
        ),
    ),
    'group' => array('Stat.offer_id'),
    'Method' => 'getStats',
    'totals' => true,
    'limit' => 20
);
```

I set these within my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the data source by calling [Model::setDatasSource()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_setDataSource).

You can change the model the paginator uses by:

```
$this->Paginator->paginate($ModelInstance);
```

Or

```
$this->Paginator->paginate('ModelName');
```

You might want to [read that page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html).

Don't use Controller::paginate any more but instead $this->Paginator->settings. For settings per model use

```
$this->Paginator->settings['ModelName'] = array(/*...*/);
```

Comment: When i try to add this it doesnt save the settings i set in the controller check my question for my settings

Comment: See updated answer. Just read the page I've linked its all there I think.